# How to convert Dockerrun.json v2 to Dockerrun.json v3 for new Docker Amazon Linux 2 Platform?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I previously used Multicontainer docker with `Dockerrun.json v2`. But now it is deprecated. AWS recommended `Docker Amazon Linux 2 Platform`. But it requires `Dockerrun.json v3`. So how to migrate from v2 to v3 ?. Or shall we can directly use `docker-compose.yml`,Or need to use Dockerrun.json v1. [with multiple containers].

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "environment": [{
      "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
      "value": "admin"
    },
      {
        "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
        "value": "postgres"
      },
      {
        "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
        "value": "somedb"
      }
    ],
    "essential": true,
    "image": "postgres:12-alpine",
    "memory": 300,
    "mountPoints": [{
      "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data/",
      "sourceVolume": "postgres_data"
    }],
    "name": "db",
    "portMappings": [{
      "containerPort": 5432,
      "hostPort": 5432
    }]
  },
    {
      "essential": true,
      "links": [
        "db"
      ],
      "name": "web",
      "image": "****.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/someimage:latest",
      "memory": 300,
      "portMappings": [{
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }]
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [{
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": "postgres_data"
    },
    "name": "postgres_data"
  }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create docker-compose.yml and don't try to build the image inside the docker-compose.yml. Push your all images into ECR, and just do refer in docker compose.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: ****.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/abc:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=***db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Like this

Answer (score 1):

In [Amazon Linux 2 Docker platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-multicontainer-migration.html), **docker-compose.yml** replaces Dockerrun.json for configuring your application services.

You don't require a `Dockerrun.json` file if you make available a `docker-compose.yml` properly configured for Amazon Linux 2 Docker platform in your source bundle and pull images from public registries or ECR repositories accessible to the Elasticbeanstalk application.

If you're pulling images from private container registries, you require an *additional* `Dockerrun.json v3` to [configure credentials for pulling images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#awsui-expandable-section-1-trigger) from it.